# How to create data template using visual studio solution, and how to bind data with template

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore-rocks

I am very new with Sitecore development, It would be great If I can get a hint from where to start to create a data template using visual studio solution(I know how to create it using User Interface i.e using sitecore Website).Currently Sitecore contains Mywebsite Folder and sitecore default folders.Need help. Thanks.

I found, how to create user defined template but when I go for creating new user defined template I don't find option to create my fields and their type. I have attached screen shot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Sitecore Rocks: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b

It's the Visual Studio integration tool for Sitecore and it will allow you to create templates from within your VS.

Comment: I found how to create template still unable to find option to create my fields and their data type inside  my template.

Comment: Finally I found it, by right clicking on template, then select edit template I got it.